# Fixing plotly legend order

Tags: r, plotly

I have a stacked bar chart with factored "colors" and I the plot itself is perfect, but the legend is reversed, the last factor is on top and the first factor is in the bottom.
This may be a dumb question, but how do I get the legends right order, without changing the plot itself?

Below an example:

```
ds <- data.frame(X = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                 Y = c(50, 10, 100, 500,
                       60, 20, 200, 600,
                       70, 30, 300, 700,
                       70, 40, 400, 700),
                 Z = c("Sugar", "Spice", "Everything nice", "Chemical X")) %>% 
    mutate(Z = factor(Z, c("Sugar", "Spice", "Everything nice", "Chemical X")))

plt <- plot_ly(ds)  %>% 
    add_trace(
        x = ~X, y = ~Y,
        color = ~Z,
        type = 'bar',
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        textposition = 'none') %>% 
    layout(bargap = 0.1, barmode = 'stack',
           legend = list(orientation = 'v',
                         yanchor = "center",
                         y = 0.5,
                         font = list(size = 17)))
plt
```

P.S. I believe this has something to do with the stacked barmode. If you deleted it the legend got the right orientation. The problem is, I need a stacked bar plot and I need in this order (c("Sugar", "Spice", "Everything nice", "Chemical X")), from bottom to top and the legend from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Just found it. The traceorder argument needs to be set inside the legend list. Thanks @maja zaloznik

```
layout(bargap = 0.1, barmode = 'stack',
      legend = list(orientation = 'v',
                    yanchor = "center",
                    traceorder = "normal", y = 0.5,
                    font = list(size = 17)))
```